# Explorer Extremely Slow after PC Repair

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I recently had my work laptop shipped off to HP to replace a faulty power supply.  Since I figured this would take a while I got an unused tower lying around the office, popped the HDD out of the laptop and stuck it in my handy USB to SATA converter and continued my work.  I worked directly off the laptop HDD for the entirety of the repair, with I would lots of continuous reading/writing to the drive (being a programmer, ctrl+s is a habit).

However, after getting the laptop back and replacing the HDD, anything I do in Windows Explorer is really slow.  Whether it be trying to open a directory or right-click on a file for the shell menu, almost any action takes 5-60 seconds, something that should happen instantly (fairly powerful laptop). I tried defragging all my partitions, and it might have had a small effect, but explorer still hangs.  Any suggestions on what would cause this would be much appreciated.

[Screencast](http://screencast.com/t/ZDcyNmI2)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 would be to check whether the HDD is configured in IDE/SATA mode. Next, I'd check for the transfer mode - Windows shifts from DMA to PIO if it encounters successive  (internal) errors and even changing mode merely reflects t, doesn't change it ( and I'm speaking this from personal experience).
Head over to device manage and remove/uninstall the HDD controller, and reboot, this will make Windows reload the drivers and switch to DMA mode. 
If you're still facing errors, use an app like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) which can perform SMART analysis on your HDD.

A virus scan using a latest updated AntiVirus can also be done to cross out virus infection related problems